# How to check if particular file names exist in a directory or not?

Tags: find, path

I have a path `/opt/backup/` which has a lot files.
Example:

```
100051
100052
100053 
etc.
```

I want to know if `100051 100052 100053` files are existing or not in `/opt/backup/` ?

Comment: Do you need to check subdirectories of `/opt/backup` as well, or are you fine with just checking in that single directory?

Comment: You have three answers that give different approaches. You have not specified in the question under what restrictions you'd like to perform this test (in an interactive shell or in a shell script), nor have you said whether the directory is a flat directory with no subdirectories or whether you'd like to search in subdirectories too. There's also the possible interpretation that you'd like to check for filenames in a general numeric range (not just three static filenames). I'm voting to close this question as unclear until you have given further information.

Answer (score 1):

You can run ls on the file names you want to check, e.g.:

```
$ ls -ld /opt/backup/10005{1,2,3}

ls: cannot access '/opt/backup/100052': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access '/opt/backup/100053': No such file or directory
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Jul  4 09:25 /opt/backup/100051
```

In this example, you can see that `/opt/backup/100051` exists, while the `/opt/backup/100052` and `/opt/backup/100053` do not.

- `-l` is optional, but I think it has more useful output
- `-d` is to prevent output of directory contents

---

If you want to check from a script, use `-f`:

```
for f in /opt/backup/10005{1,2,3}; do
  if [ -f "$f" ]; then
    echo "Exists: $f"
  else
    echo "Not Exists: $f"
  fi
done
```

Output:

```
Exists: /opt/backup/100051
Not Exists: /opt/backup/100052
Not Exists: /opt/backup/100053
```

Comment: what if i want to know if this file names are existed in path 100051 100045 100032

Comment: Change `5{1,2,3}` to `{51,45,32}`

Comment: That is called [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Brace-Expansion.html)

Comment: Or  `ls  /opt/backup/{100051,100045,100032}` Or `(cd /opt/backup; ls 100051 100045 100032)`

Comment: What is the `-a` for it does nothing, here. What is the `-l` for it does something but is it useful. `-d` would be helpful (will prevent lots of output when file is a directory).

Comment: `-a` is indeed not necessary in this case, I added `-d`.

Answer (score 0):

That's a typical usage of the [find](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) command:

```
find /opt/backup -type f -name "100051" -o -name "100052" -o -name "100053"
```

- **-type f** filters on file only
- **-o** argument means OR
- **-name** allows you to specify a name template

You can also define the number of level you want to search using `- maxdepth` or `-mindepth`

If the files are found, the output will be:

```
/opt/backup/100051
/opt/backup/100052
/opt/backup/100053
```

Answer (score 0):

When it's just a **one-off thing** and I don't really care to think much, I find **tab completion** to be a quick check for the exact name or existence of a particular file or directory (in most shells, anyway).  I usually start off with `ls` or `cat` such as:

```
ls /opt/backup/10003[TAB]
```

... where `[TAB]` is simply pressing the tab key.  The matching filename will fill in if there's only one possible completion.  If there are more than one possibilities, a list of them will be returned.  Some shells require more than one press of the `[TAB]` key before they returning a list of candidates.

```
100030    100031    100032    100033
```

It's possible of course that a shell doesn't allow tab completion by default (or at all).  In my experience that has been pretty rare.  A particular installation of an older version of Solaris comes to mind for me.

On the other hand, if you need to check for the same files again and again, other answers here would be much better at that.  The use case really isn't specified.

Comment: Like you've said, easiest quick search but unable to script it of course. Depends on use case.